# How to use resolve from middleware to controller's constructor in laravel?

Tags: laravel, middleware

Here is the middleware code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (!$user->team->id) {
        throw new BizlyException('forbidden', [], 'Access Denied.');
    }
    $team = Team::find($user->team->id);
    app()->instance('team', $team);
    app()->instance('user', $user);
    return $next($request);
}
```

So I want to user team in controller's constructor
when I use in controller's constructor it shows me the error class team does not exist.

Comment: Can you show us all of the middleware's code?